# Submitting forms automatically when the content of a text box changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a facial recognition system. When i capture image with my webcam the url is loaded into a text box in a form. Now i want the form to submit and process the php if it is submnitted. Here is my form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmsubmit">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="imgsrc" name="imgsrc">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="AUTHENTICATE" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading..." name="send" id="submit">
                                                    </form>
```

AND MY JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="JavaScript">
webcam.set_api_url( 'present.php' );
    webcam.set_quality( 100 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
    webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
    webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

    function take_snapshot(){
        // take snapshot and upload to server
        document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<h1>Uploading Image To Database...</h1>';
        webcam.snap();
    }

    function my_completion_handler(msg) {
        document.getElementById("imgsrc").value=msg;
        // extract URL out of PHP output
        if (msg.match(/(http\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
            // show JPEG image in page

            document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML ="<div class='alert alert-success fade in'> <i class='icon-remove close' data-dismiss='alert'></i> <strong>Success!</strong>Image Captured And Uploaded Successfully </div>";
            document.getElementById('upload_img').innerHTML ="<img src="+msg+" class=\"images\">";
            // reset camera for another shot
            webcam.reset();
            document.getElementById('frmsubmit').submit();
        }
        else {alert("PHP Error: " + msg);
    }
    }
</script>
```

AND PHP CODE

```
if(isset ($_POST["send"]))
```

{

Comment: i do not see the form tag to have the id="frmsubmit" attribute!

Comment: sorry i missed it in pasting the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use submit button click trigger for example

```
document.getElementById("submit").click();
```

you are using document.getElementById('frmsubmit').submit(); but you don't have any form with this id but you have submit button with id submit. so this code will work for you.

Comment: it does submit but does not run the php script and gives a blank page after refresh

Comment: @N.Felix Please try this php script <?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['imgsrc'])){
 print_r($_REQUEST['imgsrc']);
} 
?>

Answer (score 0):

if you give the form an id

```
<form action="someaction" method="post" id="someform">
```

You can trigger the `submit` event with jQuery

```
$('#someform').trigger('submit');
```

or

```
$('#someform').submit();
```

Comment: will the submit event come after my webcam snapshot method?

Comment: The event will come whenever you will trigger it in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#imgsrc').on('change', function(){
   $(this).parent().submit();
})
```

Comment: Be sure to put this script after form tag or in jQuery's document.ready method

Comment: i want to trigger this after my webcam take_snapshot() method in my javascript

Comment: Please explain your code rather than simply saying "TRY THIS."

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute onchange to the text box

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```